# Error installing package in anaconda: Attempted to make prefix record for unknown package type

Tags: ffmpeg, anaconda, conda, intel, intel-python

I'm getting the error below for doing any operation install, update or uninstall

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while
>   uninstalling package '::ffmpeg-3.2.4-2'. Rolling back
>   transaction: done
>
> ValueError('Attempted to make prefix record for unknown package type:
>   ffmpeg-3.2.4-2',)

Details about the environment:
OS: ubuntu 18.04
python version: intelpython3

Conda info

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/p****/intelpython3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/p****/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/p****/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.8.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
       base environment : /home/p****/intelpython3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/p****/intelpython3/pkgs
                          /home/p****/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/p****/intelpython3/envs
                          /home/p****/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.20.1 CPython/3.6.8 Linux/5.0.0-36-generic ubuntu/18.04.3 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Conda list

```
# packages in environment at /home/p****/intelpython3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu    anaconda
absl-py                   0.8.0                    py36_0    anaconda
affine                    2.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_3    intel
astor                     0.8.0                    py36_0    anaconda
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     19.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
audioread                 2.1.6                    py36_0    <unknown>
awscli                    1.16.292                 pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_2    <unknown>
backports                 1.0                      py36_9    <unknown>
bayesian-optimization     1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    2.1.3                    py36_2    <unknown>
boto3                     1.10.19                  pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.13.28                  pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.6                        17    intel
c-ares                    1.15.0            h7b6447c_1001    anaconda
causalgraphicalmodels     0.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2018.1.18                py36_2    intel
cffi                      1.11.5                   py36_3    intel
chardet                   3.0.4                    py36_3    intel
click                     7.0                      pypi_0    pypi
click-plugins             1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cligj                     0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
conda                     4.7.12                   py36_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py36h7b6447c_0    anaconda
cryptography              2.3                      py36_1    intel
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0  
cudnn                     7.6.0                cuda10.1_0    anaconda
cupti                     10.1.168                      0    anaconda
cvxopt                    1.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_7    intel
cython                    0.29.6           py36h7b7c402_0    intel
daal                      2019.4                intel_243    <unknown>
daal4py                   2019.4           py36h7b7c402_0    intel
dbus                      1.13.12              h746ee38_0  
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_3    <unknown>
descartes                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
docutils                  0.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
dowhy                     0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py36_2    <unknown>
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
ffmpeg                    3.2.4                         2    <unknown>
fiona                     1.8.11                   pypi_0    pypi
fontconfig                2.12.6               h49f89f6_0  
freetype                  2.8                  hab7d2ae_1  
funcsigs                  1.0.2                    py36_7    intel
gast                      0.3.2                      py_0    anaconda
geopandas                 0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py36_7    <unknown>
glib                      2.63.1               h5a9c865_0  
google-pasta              0.1.7                      py_0    anaconda
grpcio                    1.14.1           py36h9ba97e2_0    anaconda
gst-plugins-base          1.12.4               h33fb286_0  
gstreamer                 1.12.4               hb53b477_0  
h5py                      2.9.0            py36h7918eee_0    anaconda
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0    anaconda
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py36_4    <unknown>
icc_rt                    2019.4                intel_243    <unknown>
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.6                      py36_3    intel
imageio                   2.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
imgaug                    0.2.6                    pypi_0    pypi
impi_rt                   2019.4                intel_243    <unknown>
importlib-metadata        0.23                     pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2019.4                intel_243    <unknown>
intelpython               2019.4                        0    intel
ipp                       2019.4                intel_243    <unknown>
ipykernel                 4.6.1                    py36_2    <unknown>
ipython                   6.3.1                    py36_3    <unknown>
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_2    <unknown>
jedi                      0.12.0                   py36_2    <unknown>
jinja2                    2.10.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jmespath                  0.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    0.13.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
json5                     0.8.5                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7    intel
jupyter_client            5.1.0                    py36_5    <unknown>
jupyter_console           5.1.0                    py36_2    <unknown>
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py36_6    <unknown>
jupyterlab                1.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         1.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0    anaconda
keras-bert                0.80.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-embed-sim           0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-layer-normalization 0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-multi-head          0.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-pos-embd            0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-position-wise-feed-forward 0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1    anaconda
keras-rectified-adam      0.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-self-attention      0.41.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-transformer         0.31.0                   pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.0.1                    py36_2    intel
libffi                    3.2.1                        11    intel
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0    anaconda
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0    anaconda
libiconv                  1.14                          4    <unknown>
libpng                    1.6.36                        2    intel
libprotobuf               3.9.2                hd408876_0    anaconda
librosa                   0.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
libsodium                 1.0.16                        3    <unknown>
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0    anaconda
libtiff                   4.0.9                he85c1e1_1  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.8                hf84eae3_0  
lightgbm                  2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
llvmlite                  0.27.1                   py36_0    intel
markdown                  3.1.1                    py36_0    anaconda
markupsafe                1.0                      py36_3    <unknown>
matplotlib                2.1.0            py36hba5de38_0  
mercantile                1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
metaflow                  2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.3                    py36_2    <unknown>
mkl                       2019.4                intel_243    <unknown>
mkl-service               1.0.0           py36h7b7c402_11    intel
mkl_fft                   1.0.11           py36h7b7c402_2    intel
mkl_random                1.0.2            py36h7b7c402_4    intel
more-itertools            7.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mpi4py                    3.0.0                    py36_3    intel
mpmath                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
munch                     2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 5.2.1                    py36_2    <unknown>
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py36_2    <unknown>
networkx                  2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
ninja                     1.9.0            py36hfd86e86_0  
noisyopt                  0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  5.2.2                    py36_1    intel
numba                     0.42.1              np116py36_2    intel
numexpr                   2.6.8                    py36_2    intel
numpy                     1.16.2           py36h7b7c402_0    intel
numpy-base                1.16.2                   py36_0    intel
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
olefile                   0.46                       py_0  
openssl                   1.0.2r                        2    intel
packaging                 19.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    0.24.1                   py36_3    intel
pandocfilters             1.4.1                    py36_2    <unknown>
parso                     0.2.0                    py36_2    <unknown>
path.py                   11.0.1                   py36_2    <unknown>
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py36_4    <unknown>
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_3    <unknown>
pillow                    6.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.3.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pluggy                    0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                   py36_2    <unknown>
protobuf                  3.9.2            py36he6710b0_0    anaconda
ptyprocess                0.5.2                    py36_2    <unknown>
pulp                      2.0                      pypi_0    pypi
py                        1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycosat                   0.6.3                    py36_3    intel
pycparser                 2.18                     py36_2    intel
pydot                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyeditline                2.0.0                    py36_0    intel
pygments                  2.2.0                    py36_5    <unknown>
pygmy                     0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 17.5.0                   py36_2    intel
pyparsing                 2.2.0                    py36_2    intel
pyportfolioopt            0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pyproj                    2.4.2.post1              pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36h22d08a2_6  
pyrsistent                0.15.6                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.6.7                    py36_1    intel
pytesseract               0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest                    4.6.6                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.8                         7    intel
python-dateutil           2.6.0                   py36_12    intel
python-graphviz           0.13                     pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   1.3.1           py3.6_cuda10.1.243_cudnn7.6.3_0    pytorch
pytz                      2018.4                   py36_3    intel
pywavelets                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    4.1                      py36_3    intel
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py36_6    <unknown>
qt                        5.6.2               hd25b39d_14  
rasterio                  1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
regex                     2019.11.1                pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.20.1                   py36_1    intel
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
resampy                   0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rio-cogeo                 1.1.6                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       3.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py36_4    intel
s3transfer                0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sacremoses                0.0.35                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.16.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.20.3           py36h7b7c402_5    intel
scipy                     1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
seaborn                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
sentencepiece             0.1.83                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                39.0.1                   py36_0    intel
shapely                   1.6.4.post2              pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_7    <unknown>
sip                       4.18.1           py36hf484d3e_2  
six                       1.11.0                   py36_3    intel
smp                       0.1.4                    py36_0    intel
snuggs                    1.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.27.2                        4    intel
supermercado              0.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
sympy                     1.4                      pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2019.6                intel_243    <unknown>
tbb4py                    2019.6             py36_intel_0    <unknown>
tcl                       8.6.4                        24    intel
tensorboard               1.14.0           py36hf484d3e_0    anaconda
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py36h3fb9ad6_0    anaconda
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py36he45bfe2_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0    anaconda
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1    anaconda
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_2    <unknown>
testpath                  0.3.1                    py36_2    <unknown>
tk                        8.6.4                        29    intel
torchvision               0.4.2                py36_cu101    pytorch
tornado                   4.5.2                    py36_5    <unknown>
tqdm                      4.36.1                     py_0    anaconda
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_3    <unknown>
transformers              2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tweepy                    3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.22                     pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_6    <unknown>
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_0    <unknown>
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0    anaconda
wheel                     0.31.0                   py36_3    intel
widgetsnbextension        3.2.0                    py36_1    <unknown>
wrapt                     1.11.2           py36h7b6447c_0    anaconda
x264                      20131218                      0    <unknown>
xgboost                   0.81                     py36_0    intel
xz                        5.2.3                         2    intel
yaml                      0.1.7                         2    intel
zipp                      0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11                        5    intel
```

Comment: Where are all the packages with `<unknown>` origin from? Some general advice: try to avoid installing in your **base** env - it makes Conda highly likely to break. Modularize your projects to use separate envs and minimize changing them. Also, mixing Pip and Conda is rather precarious (see "[*Using Pip in a Conda environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)").

Comment: I have a habit of using pip sometimes for fast installation. It must have messed up the environment. Is there a way to correct it without reinstalling everything from start?